# How to build a sdk in scala which can be reused in other projects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sdk, reusability, code-reuse

I am new to scala and programming and I have written a class in spark scala that is generic and should be reused by other projects. How can I build a sdk in scala sbt so that I can reuse this class without re writing the code again. Any online documentation would help.

Comment: Publish your code as a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're calling a "sdk" sounds more like what we call a "library".

The high level steps are:

- create your library project (regular sbt project)
- configure this project for publishing
- publish the project to a repository (Artifactory, Nexus..) or optionally publish locally if you don't need a repository
- in any other project, add your library project as a dependency

I would recommend reading the sbt documentation which should cover the most of it. For instance, [Publishing with sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Publishing).